# Decode base64 string - php

Tags: php, base64

Is there any way to decode this string??

Actual string : 其他語言測試 - testing

base64 encode while sending on mail as subject as

"=?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCQjZCPjhsOEBCLDtuGyhCIC0gdGVzdGluZw==?="

```
<?php
echo base64_decode('GyRCQjZCPjhsOEBCLDtuGyhCIC0gdGVzdGluZw==');
?>
```

This is base 64 encode, I couldn't decode it to actual Chinese string.Since it has been encoded using "iso-2022-jp", I have also tried online base64decode.org site to decode this string, but I couldn't find the original string, how can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)? `mb_convert_encoding(base64_decode($str));`

Comment: This is my result: `5YW25LuW6Kqe6KiA5ris6KmmIC0gdGVzdGluZw==` and while I decoded I get `其他語言測試 - testing` but when tested yours I can't see original text

Comment: @Steven Liao i tried the following {mb_convert_encoding(base64_decode($str),'iso-2022-jp');}    result: ??-?x

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php):

```
<?php
$input = base64_decode('GyRCQjZCPjhsOEBCLDtuGyhCIC0gdGVzdGluZw==');//$BB6B>8l8@B,;n(B - testing
$input_encoding = 'iso-2022-jp';
echo iconv($input_encoding, 'UTF-8', $input); //其他語言測試 - testing
?>
```

Comment: is there a way to find the what is encoding format by giving this string as input {$str ='=?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCQjZCPjhsOEBCLDtuGyhCIC0gdGVzdGluZw==?='};

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at is MIME header encoding. It can be decoded by [`mb_decode_mimeheader()`](http://php.net/mb_decode_mimeheader), and generated by [`mb_encode_mimeheader()`](http://php.net/mb_encode_mimeheader). For example:

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");
$subj = "=?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCQjZCPjhsOEBCLDtuGyhCIC0gdGVzdGluZw==?=";
print mb_decode_mimeheader($subj);
?>

其他語言測試 - testing
```

(The call to `mb_internal_encoding()` is necessary here because the contents of the subject line can't be represented in the default internal encoding of ISO8859-1.)

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding the string to UTF-8 first and then encode it to base 64.
Same when decoding, decode the string from base64 and then from UTF-8.
This is working for me:

```
php > $base = "其他語言測試 - testing";
php > $encoded = base64_encode(utf8_encode($base));
php > $decoded = utf8_decode(base64_decode($encoded));
php > echo ($decoded === $base) . "\n";
1
```

Comment: i am not converting it, when i send mail using outlook and subject to chineses character, when i read the stream i am getting like this, so how to decode it, that is present in iso-2022-jp format?