# Encrypt PHP query string value in URL

Tags: php

Here is my question, i am trying to hide address value in URL

URL is something like this

```
example.com/linkdl/preview/index.php?address='http://mysiteexample.com'
```

I am trying to hide, `?address='http://mysiteexample.com'` part, but i am not sure, what is best way

i have an idea to use `base64_encode($adresa)`, but i am not sure will i have problems with (encoding/decoding special) characters in URL

```
$click = 'OtvoriProzor("'.$file_path.'&pk='.$sesija->pk.'&adresa='.base64_encode($adresa).
                    '&IDIstorijaElement='.$element->GetId().'", "Prevod", 700, 500);';
```

This is very insecure, can add some function for encryption, to encrypt and decrypt parametar, or will md5 help me here. Also should i use function url_decode url_decode instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decode base64 string - php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842075/decode-base64-string-php)

Comment: use POST instead of GET... and when you want to secure your data, use https instead of http

Comment: Please specify for what purpose you want to "hide" that value. Aesthetic reasons? "Security"? Secrecy? What exactly do you need to protect then from whom?

Comment: Secrecy i want to prevent direct download, its address for direct download, its impossible to use post because system is based on GET

Comment: Provide more details. Download from where? Where would one get such a link from? How would encrypting that value fundamentally provide an improvement.

Comment: its students learning platform, on one click you have link wich opens pdf file. This works with GET, in parametar adress there is link from server. I want to hide this

Answer (score 5):

Since md5 is a hash algorithm, you won't be able to get back what you encoded.
You can use base64 and urlencode to avoid problems with some characters:

```
<?php
$url = urlencode(base64_encode($adresa));
?>
```

And you will decode it with:

```
<?php
$addr = base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['adresa']));
?>
```

Comment: can i use crypt functions

Comment: 1) Your decoding needs to be reversed, 2) this is merely light obfuscation, nothing is hidden here.

Comment: You won't get the clean url in the GET parameter, I don't have to reverse anything

Comment: If you first base 64 encode, then url encode, you need to reverse this by first url decoding, then base 64 decoding.